# Blank bar in side menu

Tags: html, ios, ionic-framework

In my app I am working with ionic, the app work pretty good in android but in ios show some arbitarary response. When we open side bar in ios ionic app is shows a blank bar in side menu and also overflow over the top action bar like this

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: https://ideone.com/ETWMoM